# Newbie with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have just yum installed mongodbmongodb.x86_64, 2.2.3-4.el6, on redhat linux.

1. Did an rpm -ql mongodb and it shows:

   /usr/bin/bsondump
   /usr/bin/mongo
   /usr/bin/mongodump
   /usr/bin/mongoexport
   /usr/bin/mongofiles
   /usr/bin/mongoimport
   /usr/bin/mongooplog
   /usr/bin/mongoperf
   /usr/bin/mongorestore
   /usr/bin/mongosniff
   /usr/bin/mongostat
   /usr/bin/mongotop
   /usr/share/man/man1/bsondump.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongo.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongodump.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongoexport.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongofiles.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongoimport.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongorestore.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongosniff.1.gz
   /usr/share/man/man1/mongostat.1.gz
2. Starting mongodb:  service mongod start

   mongod: unrecognized service
3. typed:  mongo

I get this:

```
exec error: src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91 couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
db = new Mongo().getDB( url );
```

I have no ideas what to do.  I have tried to follow the documentation but not sure if it is the right step.  I want to start mongodb and create a directory in /opt/app/data/db directory.  This is where I have a mounted a share.  Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, looks like you only installed the client package... Your file list does not show he server binary.

Comment: Ok, I yum install mongodb-server and try to start mongod with: service mongod start.  I got this error Starting mongod: runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted.